# Jsoup parsing - Java

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to parse data from IMDB and Rotten Tomatoes using Jsoup.  I've gotten most of the info I need but there is some data I don't know how to get.

For example in the movie [The Expendables 2](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_expendables_2/) I need to get the number for User Reviews: `313,393` (just the number) but using something like

```
Elements links19 = doc5.select("p[class=critic_stats]");
```

gets the whole `p class="critic_stats"`

> Average Rating: 5.8/10 Reviews Counted: 123 Fresh: 80 | Rotten: 43 Average Rating: 5.3/10 Critic Reviews: 23 Fresh: 13 | Rotten: 10 liked it Average Rating: 3.7/5 User Ratings: 313,393

For the same movie in [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1764651/) I'm trying to get:

```
Country: USA | Bulgaria
Language: English
Release Date: 17 August 2012 (USA) 
Sound Mix: Dolby Digital | Datasat
Color: Color
Aspect Ratio: 2.35 : 1
```

Again I only need the values but everything is in

```
<div class="txt-block">
<h4 class="inline">
```

and I don't know if there's any way to get specific data based on for example

```
<h4 class="inline">Sound Mix:</h4>

<itemprop='url'>Dolby Digital</a>
<itemprop='url'>Datasat</a>
```

Any ideas on how to get those .. I'm not sure what they are, child attributes?

**UPDATE:**

OK so the first worked with
`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*\\.?,?[0-9]+");`

I have a few more questions

I need to get `"/title/tt1764651/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1"` or even better the whole http

from

`<tr class="findResult odd"> <td class="primary_photo"> <a href="/title/tt1764651/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1" ><img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQzODkwNDQxNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTQ1ODAxOA@@._V1_SX32_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg" /></a> </td> <td class="result_text"> <a href="/title/tt1764651/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1" >The Expendables 2</a> (2012) </td></tr></table>`

I tried

`Elements links = doc.select("table[class=findList");
String a= links.attr("abs:href");`

but it doesn't work, any ideas?

Also I used

`Document doc6= Jsoup.parse(new URL(url6).openStream(), "ISO-8859-1", url6);`

to get the Also Known As but on the Bulgarian title for example I get

Bulgaria (Bulgarian title) ???µ?????±?µ???????????µ

@Spectre

Comment: Note that the application you are describing is likely in direct violation of [IMDB's terms of service](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1764651/): "*You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site"*.

Answer (score 2):

jsoup only provides manipulation of HTML. It can get you slight further than your attempt but not much:

```
Element el = doc.select("p.critic_status").last();
```

Will get you the element containing:

*"Rotten: 10 liked it Average Rating: 3.7/5 User Ratings: 313,393"*

This is because there are no further sub-elements to be able to dig into. To extract the data you want will require using other text-processing tools. For example using regular expressions:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("User Ratings: ([0-9,]+)");
Matcher = pattern.matcher(el.text());
if(matcher.matches()) {
    String userRating = matcher.group(1); // "313,393"
}
```

For your second question, you need to chain selectors:

```
doc.select("div.txt-block");                   // <div class=<txt-block">

doc.select("div.txt-block > h4.inline");       // <h4 class="inline">
doc.select("div.txt-block > a[itemprop=url]"); // <a href="..." itemprop="url">
```

jsoup selectors are documented in the Selector class. Also Jsoup is modelled after jQuery so that documentation is also useful:

- [jsoup: org.jsoup.select.Selector](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)
- [jQuery: Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)